# how to change workspaces with touchpad gestures in touchegg on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad, workspace

I tried this instructions with touchegg: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92169/to ... -workspace
My goal is to be able to change between workspaces with touchpad gestures(My sugested gesture for this is horisontal scrolling). None of the commands set in the touchegg.conf works. How do I get this to work or does another solution exists?

I run Linux Mint 17.1 on a lenovo g510 i7 laptop.

Answer (score 1):

use the software easystroke.
go to the tab action,
add action,
click on record stroke:tip on the touchpad and swipe left,
choose as type: key combination, and type ctrl alt leftarrow

now add 2nd action, do the same but swipe right and type ctrl alt rightarrow,

add 3rd action swipe up...ctrl alt uparrow.

Now you have the keyboard shortcuts to switch workspace activated on your touchpad enjoy:)